# VBA to read the first selection in a drop down and run macro

Tags: excel, vba, call, dropdown

I have two drop down lists, the second one is dependent on the selection of the first one to grab the corresponding value from another sheet. I've gotten it to call a separate Macro whenever the selection matches the criteria.

For some reason It reads all entries and runs macros except for the first entry "one". Any idea why it will not read the first entry but reads everything else?

If you want the code that its calling for "One" let me know, however, i did test that macro and it works perfectly, its just not being called..

Heres my coding (Short Version).

```
Sub DataGrab()

    Dim BC As Variant
    Dim BT As Variant

    BC = Range("A2")
    BT = Range("B2")


'90's One
If BC = "_90s" And BT = "One" Then
    Call Data90s1

'90's Two
ElseIf BC = "_90s" And BT = "Two" Then
    Call Data90s2

 '90's Three
ElseIf BC = "_90s" And BT = "Three" Then
    Call Data90s3

'90's Four
ElseIf BC = "_90s" And BT = "Four" Then
    Call Data90s4
End If
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you attempted to make the drop downs dependent without code?  using named ranges and `indirect()` you can achieve this... that doesn't answer your issue with your code, but is something to look into.

Comment: For the sake of it, have you tried `application.run("Data90s1")`, rather than `Call`?

Comment: I didn't see from your post... did you step through (F8) to make sure that `_90s` and `One` are moving inside of the condition?

Comment: I have done the INDIRECT connection on the page. The main drop down has 8 different categories, Then the second drop down has anywhere from 4-14 values depending on the first selection

Comment: I tried the application run and it doesnt do anything..  I ran through the code using F8 and it reads the first line. It does highlight the call section of the codes until it gets to the bottom tho.. like i said tho it does call the programs for everything from "Two" and beyond... its weird

Comment: "It does highlight the call section of the codes until it gets to the bottom tho"  What?

Comment: Sorry I meant doesn't highlight.. When i hit F8, it only highlights the ElseIf sections of the code. Not sure if that means its reading the lines or not.. (Still newer to VBA)

Comment: Ok guys... i selected the group of cells that contains the information for the drop downs.. I re entered the word "One" into the reference cell and now it works just fine... I swear sometimes computers just hate me.. Sorry for all the troubles.. Thanks so much!

Comment: You may have had a leading/ending space or didn't have the same capitalization.  Happens

Comment: Ted, take a look at my answer as a just in case... you can circumvent issues with leading/ending spaces or capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

I did not have any issues triggering any condition/case using your code, but do have the below recommendation to utilize `ucase()` and `like` to play it safe with entry of data and what values you are comparing for your conditions:

```
Sub DataGrab()
    Dim BC As Variant, BT As Variant
    BC = Range("A2")
    BT = Range("B2")
    Select Case True
        Case BC = "_90s" And UCase(BT) Like "*ONE*" '90's One
            Debug.Print UCase(BT)
            Call Data90s1
        Case BC = "_90s" And UCase(BT) Like "*TWO*"  '90's Two
            Debug.Print UCase(BT)
            'Call Data90s2
        Case BC = "_90s" And UCase(BT) Like "*THREE*"  '90's Three
            Debug.Print UCase(BT)
            'Call Data90s3
        Case BC = "_90s" And UCase(BT) Like "*FOUR*"  '90's Four
            Debug.Print UCase(BT)
            'Call Data90s4
    End Select
End Sub

Sub Data90s1()
    Debug.Print "Hello"
End Sub
```